# How do I unwrap this texture for this box mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv, workflow

How do I unwrap this texture image for my box mesh?

[image]

This is my texture image:

[image]

---

I tried unwrapping the image texture and this was the result:

[image]

Comment: Hi :). This depends on your UV map. Open the UV map editor and make sure it aligns with the image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn on the "Shader editor", load the image and attach it to the color. Then you have to unwrap your model. Turn on the UV editor in another window, select your image.

[image]

turn on "edit mode" select the edges along which you want to "unwrap" your model, select mark seam in the drop-down menu. Press "U" twice. Adjust the expanded model to yours. In general, it would be nice to see some simple tutorial about UV unwrapping.
[image]

Attached file:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's a good idea to import the Image Texture as reference and position the box in such a way that you can visualize where to put the *Seams* for proper unwrapping. Go <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* then press <kbd>2</kbd> to switch to *Edge Select* mode. Then click those edges as shown below and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> *> Mark Seams*. This will turn the edges red and allow for cleaner box unwrapping.

[image]

Select all the outer faces when viewing from under the box and press <kbd>U</kbd> *> Unwrap*. Then in *UV Editor* you can rotate and scale the UV faces as shown below

[image]

Add a material and add the material nodes as shown below then load the Image Texture.

[image]

Go back to *UV Editor* and make the appropriate scale adjustments for UV faces to perfectly fit into the texture.

[image]

[image]